# Split JSON string column to multiple columns without schema - PySpark

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a delta table which has a column with JSON data. I do not have a schema for it and need a way to convert the JSON data into columns

```
|id | json_data
| 1 | {"name":"abc", "depts":["dep01", "dep02"]}
| 2 | {"name":"xyz", "depts":["dep03"],"sal":100}
| 3 | {"name":"pqr", "depts":["dep02"], "address":{"city":"SF"}}
```

Expected output

```
|id | name    | depts              | sal | address_city 
| 1 | "abc"   | ["dep01", "dep02"] | null| null         
| 2 | "xyz"   | ["dep03"]          | 100 | null         
| 3 | "pqr"   | ["dep02"]          | null| "SF"
```

Comment: You can try parse it to map type `map<string,string>`  then explode it and pivot the values.

Answer (score 4):

**Input Dataframe** -

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = [(1 , """{"name":"abc", "depts":["dep01", "dep02"]}"""), (2 , """{"name":"xyz", "depts":["dep03"],"sal":100}"""), (3 , """{"name":"pqr", "depts":["dep02"], "address":{"city":"SF"}}""")], schema = ["id", "json_data"])
df.show(truncate=False)

+---+----------------------------------------------------------+
|id |json_data                                                 |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"name":"abc", "depts":["dep01", "dep02"]}                |
|2  |{"name":"xyz", "depts":["dep03"],"sal":100}               |
|3  |{"name":"pqr", "depts":["dep02"], "address":{"city":"SF"}}|
+---+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Convert `json_data` column to `MapType` as below -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df1 = df.withColumn("cols", from_json("json_data", MapType(StringType(), StringType()))).drop("json_data")
df1.show(truncate=False)

+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|id |cols                                                       |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{name -> abc, depts -> ["dep01","dep02"]}                  |
|2  |{name -> xyz, depts -> ["dep03"], sal -> 100}              |
|3  |{name -> pqr, depts -> ["dep02"], address -> {"city":"SF"}}|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now, column `cols` needs to be exploded as below -

```
df2 = df1.select("id",explode("cols").alias("col_columns", "col_rows"))
df2.show(truncate=False)

+---+-----------+-----------------+
|id |col_columns|col_rows         |
+---+-----------+-----------------+
|1  |name       |abc              |
|1  |depts      |["dep01","dep02"]|
|2  |name       |xyz              |
|2  |depts      |["dep03"]        |
|2  |sal        |100              |
|3  |name       |pqr              |
|3  |depts      |["dep02"]        |
|3  |address    |{"city":"SF"}    |
+---+-----------+-----------------+
```

Once, you have `col_columns` and `col_rows` as individual columns, all that is needed to do is `pivot` `col_columns` and aggregate it using its corresponding `first` `col_rows` as below -

```
df3 = df2.groupBy("id").pivot("col_columns").agg(first("col_rows"))
df3.show(truncate=False)

+---+-------------+-----------------+----+----+
|id |address      |depts            |name|sal |
+---+-------------+-----------------+----+----+
|1  |null         |["dep01","dep02"]|abc |null|
|2  |null         |["dep03"]        |xyz |100 |
|3  |{"city":"SF"}|["dep02"]        |pqr |null|
+---+-------------+-----------------+----+----+
```

Finally, you again need to repeat the above steps to bring `address` in structured format as below -

```
df4 = df3.withColumn("address", from_json("address", MapType(StringType(), StringType())))
df4.select("id", "depts", "name", "sal",explode_outer("address").alias("key", "address_city")).drop("key").show(truncate=False)

+---+-----------------+----+----+------------+
|id |depts            |name|sal |address_city|
+---+-----------------+----+----+------------+
|1  |["dep01","dep02"]|abc |null|null        |
|2  |["dep03"]        |xyz |100 |null        |
|3  |["dep02"]        |pqr |null|SF          |
+---+-----------------+----+----+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve it you can use split function as code below.

The function takes 2 parameters, the first one is the column itself and the second is the pattern to split the elements from column array.

More information and examples cand be found here:

[https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-convert-string-to-array-column/#:~:text=PySpark%20SQL%20provides%20split(),and%20converting%20it%20into%20ArrayType](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-convert-string-to-array-column/#:%7E:text=PySpark%20SQL%20provides%20split(),and%20converting%20it%20into%20ArrayType).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select(F.split(F.col('depts'), ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse and promote the properties from a JSON string column **without a known schema** dynamically, I am afraid you cannot use pyspark, it can be done by using Scala.

For example when you have some avro files produced by Kafka, and you want to be able to parse the `Value` which is a serialized JSON string dynamically

```
var df = spark.read.format("avro").load("abfss://abc@def.dfs.core.windows.net/xyz.avro").select("Value")
var df_parsed = spark.read.json(df.as[String])
display(df_parsed)
```

The key is `spark.read.json(df.as[String])` in Scala, it basically

1. Convert that DF ( it has only one column that we are interested in in this case, you can of course deal with multiple interested columns similarily and union whatever you want ) to `String`.
2. Parse the JSON string using standard spark read option, this does not require a schema.

So far there is no equivalent methods exposed to pyspark as far as I know.